# Finding the first occurrence of a given/ specific character inside every word

Tags: javascript, regex

`stringi = "fuunnynsdfdn dfdfomdfdnd dfdfnntr ndfdf thatnfdfdfdfd"`

I was able to make a regEx to DYNAMICALLY find every last occurrence of a character X in every word: (I call it dynamically because I only have to change ONE spot)

`(n)(?!(\w+?)?\1(\w+?)?)` gives

```
"fuunnynsdfdn dfdfomdfdnd dfdfnntr ndfdf thatnfdfdfdfd"
            ^          ^       ^   ^         ^
```

`(d)(?!(\w+?)?\1(\w+?)?)` gives

```
"fuunnynsdfdn dfdfomdfdnd dfdfnntr ndfdf thatnfdfdfdfd"
           ^            ^   ^         ^              ^
```

#### Question:

How can I get a "dynamic" regEx. That means I have to replace one spot like above to give me:

`some regEx with >>> n <<<` gives

```
"fuunnynsdfdn dfdfomdfdnd dfdfnntr ndfdf thatnfdfdfdfd"
    ^                  ^      ^    ^         ^
```

`some regEx with >>> d <<<` gives

```
"fuunnynsdfdn dfdfomdfdnd dfdfnntr ndfdf thatnfdfdfdfd"
         ^    ^           ^         ^          ^
```

Is it possible to match those with a regEx and that I only have to change ONE spot when I want to match another character?

#### Please note:

Pure regEx, no js string splitting etc..

#### The Problem

With the lookbehind I run into a fixed length problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That means I have to replace one spot

You first match `n` then every thing else:

```
n(\S*)
```

```js
var str = "fuunnynsdfdn dfdfomdfdnd dfdfnntr ndfdf thatnfdfdfdfd";
var char = 'n';
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp(char + '(\\S*)', 'g'), '*$1'));
var char = 'd';
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp(char + '(\\S*)', 'g'), '*$1'));
```

If it's a matter of interest, since Chrome has [implemented lookbehinds](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) (that luckily are infnite lookbehinds) you can acheive same result with this regex:

```
(?<!n\S*)n
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5sdfC/1)

Comment: You said you need to replace one spot. If you run the code snippet in answer you will see how it works. @AndreElrico

Comment: Yeah, your solution is absolutely constructive. I was just curious if I would match them directly, like getting highlighted on regex101.

Comment: Yes, this is also correct. Yet it won't work on all regEx interpreter (PHP) and I have to change 2 spots. Anyways I'm waisting too much time for nothing. Thank you a lot for wrapping you're head around this thing.

Comment: Not all regex flavors support infinite lookbehinds. .NET is capable. PHP isn't. JS is going to be shipped with it. You can do `(n)(?<!\1\S*.)` too which needs one spot to be changed. This works in Chrome but for the reason that I don't know it doesn't work on regex101. @AndreElrico

Answer (score 1):

In [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lx9UUz/2), the lookbehind seems to be okay with not fixed length - with javascript. So this is the regex:

```
(?<=\b[^\Wd]*)d
```

Explanation:

- `\b` is a word barrier
- `[^d]*d` finds non-`d` characters, and then a `d`
- `[^\Wd]` is not a `d` but word characters. I.e. `\W` is not a word character, so `[^\W]` is a word character. So `[^\Wd]` is every word character, except `d`
- `\b[^\Wd]*d` would match the start of every word, up to the first `d`. Using the right constructs, this could be enough.
- `(?<=...)` is the lookbehind.

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported by all major browsers yet.

Comment: The result on regEx101 is what I want for JS flavor. Yet I would have to change 2 spots when I want to go from "d" to "n". Not sure if this can be done how I imagined it.

Comment: Is is a play-around thing? If you are going to implement this on a serious environment you should know that only Chrome supports lookbehinds as of now. @AndreElrico

Comment: @revo Yes, it's more like a question of interest in order to learn something. Your solution is, of course, stable and constructive.